# When I have width: auto and specific left and right, why does setting min-width to the value of calculated width expand the element by 2px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page made of elements with width and height set to auto and their dimensions defined with left, right, top and bottom properties. When the page is loaded, all widths and heights are set to their calculated values by the browser, as they should be. However, when I set min-width of the elements to their respective calculated widths, each of those elements is expanded by 2px. The same happens if I set their min-height to be equal to the calculated height. I do it with jQuery, like this

```
element.css('min-width', element.css('width'));
```

or

```
element.css('min-width', element.width());
```

The effect is exactly the same as it should be, but there should not be the extra 2px if I understand what's happening correctly. Using

```
element.css('min-width', element.width() - 2);
```

completely solves the problem but I don't like not understanding why there are the extra 2px. According to specifications, neither width nor min-width nor max-width should include padding, borders or margins.

I've tested in Chrome and FF and both behave the same way.

Comment: Have you tried to set borders width, paddings and margins to 0? Please create a sample using http://jsfiddle.net/ and add it to your post.

Comment: the problem is with your `.width()` which gets the overall width or the outermost width i think, maybe `.width()` should be `.css('width')` read somewhere about this but look at the difference of the two :) should give you an answer

Comment: take a look at your elements using Firebug. Sometimes you maybe inheriting something  from a parent element you don't even realize.

Comment: My money is also on padding, margins or borders being responsible - try setting all of these to zero, to see if it helps.

Comment: It's ok without borders, but it doesn't make sense. CSS positions refer to the outer edges of the element's margin, while CSS dimensions and min/max dimensions do not include padding, borders or margins. If I have `width: auto; left: 0px; right: 200px; border-width: 1px;`, calculated width should be 198px and setting min-width and/or max-width to that value should not change the dimensions of my element.

Comment: @Val: `$(element).width()` == parseInt($(element).css('width')). `$(element).innerWidth()` returns integer width with padding (width of the area the background is applied to). `$(element).outerWidth()` returns integer width with padding and borders. `$(element).outerWidth(true)' returns integer width with padding, borders and margins.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you testing and can it be that your document is in quirksmode?

`element.css('min-width', element.width());` shouldn't be doing anything in standards mode, because `element.width()` returns an integer without a CSS unit, and `min-width` requires a unit in standardsmode.

So put your document in standards mode and then try:

```
element.css('min-width', element.width() + "px");
```

If that doesn't help you'll need to show a working example.

Comment: My Chrome says it is in CSS1Compat mode and `element.css('min-width', element.width())` and `element.css('min-width', element.css('width'))` are working exactly the same. I've never had to add the 'px' string. I think jQuery .css() method automatically converts integers to pixels for positions and dimensions.